# Custom Zk Combobox

Tags: java, zk

as seen in:

http://www.zkoss.org/zkdemo/combobox/simple_combobox

When the item is selected only text appears.
How can I make the image + name appear when the item is selected?

which method from Combobox do i need to override?

ty

Comment: I would look into [Macro Components](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/Macro_Components), maybe putting an `Image` right before the `Combobox` and updating it according to the selected item (`onSelect`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no build-in way for you to do things like that. Because a `Combobox` is just a textbox with a customizable drop-down list.

But this can be done pretty easily. You can just add an `Image` at left of the combobox, and listen combobox   `Events.ON_SELECT` event. Then update the `Image` according to selected item.

Here is an example code (assuming use `SelectorComposer`)

```
@Listen("onSelect = combobox#mycmb")
public void onComboboxSelected(SelectEvent event) {
  Set<MyObject> selectedObjects = event.getSelectedObjects();
  MyObject obj = selectedObjects.get(0);

  image.setSrc(getImagePath(obj));  // image are Image component you wired.
}
```

*Note : I didn't test the code, but you should get the idea*